# What kind of dishes use fresh coriander fruits

Tags: culinary-uses, herbs, coriander

I grew some cilantro in my garden and allowed some of it to go to seed. Most commonly, I've seen the seed pods dried and ground. Where I live at least, the fresh leaves are referred to as cilantro and the dried seeds are sold as coriander. What I tried, was using the fresh green seed pods in a soup and I loved it. The seed pods have a more balanced flavour in comparison to the leaves with additional fragrant citrus notes.

What I'm wondering is if this is common practice or if anyone has any other ideas for using these pods.

Comment: Don't have any advice but thanks for the info, going to try it.

Comment: No idea if it's common practice, but it's awesome that you're experimenting. I say let your palate lead the way.

Comment: Thanks guys. I should mention that I removed the tough stems and mashed the seed pods with a mortar and pestle. The whole pods also freeze much better than the leaves do.

Comment: The roots are also used in some cuisines.  I find they're not as overpoweringly soapy as the leaves are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an article that suggests using on seafood/white fleshed fish. http://www.nytimes.com/2009/08/19/dining/19cori.html

Answer (score 1):

I've done much the same thing here although with actual Coriander rather than Cilantro. As I understand it they are separate herbs, but with similar properties.

I can understand the desire to differentiate, by name, the seeds and leaves, you may find that the coriander seeds you buy are actually coriander, and the cilantro plants/leaves you get are actually cilantro. Unfortunately I don't know if there are differences in green-cilantro seed to green coriander seed.

I have however used the coriander green seed in a fair number of different dishes. Mixing in with rice, or any rich dish is a good place to start. I bruise (not crush) the seeds in a mortar & pestle, then add them to things like Paella, or even plain rice. Also as a late-addition to stews and so on. It also works well with chicken.

In short, kinda like Cilantro you really can go wild. I love the flavor so I'm game to throw it at anything, but of course it goes especially well with anything spicy.

Comment: I could not find any information indicating that [coriander and cilantro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriander) are separate, but similar, herbs. Are you sure you are not thinking of [culantro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culantro) rather than cilantro?